# Call function2() inside function1() but it is getting fired before .subscribe()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, function, local-storage

I have 2 functions in my login.component.ts, I want to call `function2()` as soon as `function1()` is over, but it is getting called before `.subscribe()`. Why is this happening and how can I correct it?

Below is my code:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule  } from '@angular/http';
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';
import { LoginService } from './login.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  providers: [LoginService],
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})


export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
     public user_form_value = 'info@lamchemical.com';
     public password_form_value = 'lam';
     public loggeduser_array = [];

     constructor(private _loginService: LoginService) { }

     login2(){
    console.log(this.user_form_value);
    console.log(this.password_form_value);
    this._loginService.login(this.user_form_value, this.password_form_value).subscribe(
      res =>{
        console.log(res.user);
      localStorage.setItem("getLoggedInUserANG",JSON.stringify(res.user));
      this.loggeduser_array  = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("getLoggedInUserANG"));
     // console.log((this.loggeduser_array as any).name);
      console.log(this.loggeduser_array["name"]);    
    }
      )
   this.login_true_2();
  }


login_true_2(){
  if(localStorage.getItem("getLoggedInUserANG") != null) {
  alert("you are in");
 } else {
  alert("Wrong username or password");
 }
}

 
 ngOnInit() {
}
}
```

To explain more clearly, let me add numbers as what is executing in which turn

1. I see this message in console - `console.log(this.user_form_value)`
2. Then I see - `console.log(this.password_form_value)`
3. Then I see the alert - `alert("Wrong username or password")`
4. Then I see - `console.log(res.user)` and finally
5. `console.log(this.loggeduser_array["name"])`

Now, if I'll press the button again to call the `login2()` function, this time I'll see alert - `alert("you are in")`, why second time, I want it to work first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the `login_true_2` method within the subscribe handler, otherwise it will called before the local storage is set because the `login` method is asynchronous.

Second time it is working because by the time second click happens, the local storage value is already set by the first call.

```
  login2() {
    console.log(this.user_form_value);
    console.log(this.password_form_value);
    this._loginService.login(this.user_form_value, this.password_form_value).subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res.user);
        localStorage.setItem("getLoggedInUserANG", JSON.stringify(res.user));
        this.loggeduser_array = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("getLoggedInUserANG"));
        // console.log((this.loggeduser_array as any).name);
        console.log(this.loggeduser_array["name"]);
        this.login_true_2();
      }
    )
  }
```

Comment: Worked, many times i read its asynchronous or synchronous but this fundamental is not clear to me, can you please help me understanding this